# Can't display data from my database

Tags: php, mysql, forms, post, get

I am trying to allow users to select restrictions from my database by using 3 drop down boxes. I have set them up and I have connected to my database. However, once the user hits the submit button, I can't get data to be displayed in a table. Here is my code:

```
<?php
require_once 'connection.php';
?>


<form action="stats.php" method ="post">
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true" />

<fieldset>
<legend>
Specify Date, Month, and County
</legend>
<p>
<label for="year">
Please select a year
</label>

<select name= 'year'>
<?php
$query = "select distinct year from unemployed";

$result = $conn->query($query);
while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
  echo "<option value='".$row->year."'>".$row->year."</option>";
 }
?>
</select>
</p>

<p>
<label for="month">
Please select a month
<label>

<select name= 'month'>
<?php
$query = "select distinct month from unemployed";

$result = $conn->query($query);
while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
  echo "<option value='".$row->month."'>".$row->month."</option>";
 }
?>
</select>
</p>

<p>
<label for="location">
Please specify a location
</label>

<select name='select'>
<?php
$query = "select * from unemployed";

$result = $conn->query($query);

while ($finfo = $result->fetch_field()) {
  echo "<option value='".$finfo->name."'>".$finfo->name."</option>";
 }

?>
</select>
</p>


<input type ="submit" />

</fieldset>
</form>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {

include('connection.php');

$gYear = $_POST["year"];
$gMonth = $_POST["month"];
$gSelect = $_POST["select"];

$query = "select $gSelect from unemployed where year='$gYear' and month='$gMonth'";

$result = $conn->query($query) or die('error getting data');


echo"<table>";
echo "<tr><th>Year</th><th>Time</th><th>$gSelect</th></tr>";

while ($row = $result->fetch_object()){

echo "<tr><td>";
echo $row['Year'];
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row['Month'];
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row['$gSelect'];
echo "</td></tr>";

}




echo "</table";

} // end of main if statement

?>
```

I can't get the data to be displayed in a table at all. I have tried multiple ways, but I am still getting errors. To ensure that I am connected to my database, I used var_dump($row) to make sure, and that worked okay. So that is not the problem. Does anyone have any idea what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3):

When you retrieve the data from your result set you're fetching it as an object:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_object()){
```

But when you come to display it, you refer to it as an array:

```
echo "<tr><td>";
echo $row['Year'];   // array syntax.
```

You should be using object syntax:

```
echo "<tr><td>";
echo $row->Year;   // object syntax.
```

If you check your error logs you should see a lot of messages to this effect.